# .NET Framework: How to update System.Runtime?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

I have a DLL compiled from a project of type "Class Library" which has a target framework of `netcoreapp3.1` (EDIT: now `netstandard2.0`).

I then reference this DLL in another project, a Windows Forms application, which targets .NET Framework `4.7.2` (EDIT: now `4.8`).

When trying to compile the Windows Forms application, I get the following error:

```
Error CS1705: Assembly 'BC' with identity 'BC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

I would like to update `System.Runtime` on the WinForms project to use version 4.2.2.0 (which is apparently required by my DLL), however, I found no way to do so - there are no NuGet packages installed and the references section in Visual Studio doesn't seem to include `System.Runtime` directly:

[image: references list screenshot, System.Runtime does not appear in the list]

How do I update `System.Runtime` and resolve the error?

Comment: @jdweng, I tried rebuilding and removing then adding the reference to my library, but the error persists.

Comment: Not possible.  The library project needs to target .NETStandard to be usable in a legacy .NETFramework project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try any of the following:

- Upgrade your WinForms project to .NET 4.8, because there have been a lot of compatibility fixes in that release. .NET 4.8 still has issues when interfacing with .NET Core libs, but many problems will just be gone.
- Or try changing your library to .netstandard2.0. Then it should always be compatbile to Net Framework.

For best compatiblity, try doing both: Setting the library to .netstandard2.0 and change the WinForms app to .NET 4.8.

Comment: After restarting Visual Studio I was able to target .netstandard2.0 in the library project, but the error persists in the WinForms project (which now uses .NET Framework 4.8).

Comment: Some cleaning and restarts later, it all worked as expected. Thank you!